# Prove that a set is sigma finite

Tags: real-analysis

Let $(X, \mathcal{F}, \mu)$ be a $\sigma$-finite measure space and let $A$ in $F$ be such that $\mu(A)=\infty$. Prove that there exists $B$ in $ \mathcal{F}$, $B\subset A$, such that $0< \mu(B)< \infty$ .

My approach: since $\mu$ has a finite measure the $X$ is the union of countably many disjoint sets which are finite. Have no idea what do then? Can someone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $X=\displaystyle \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty E_n$ with $\mu(E_n)<\infty$ then $$A=A\cap X=\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty (A \cap E_n)$$

If all sets $A\cap E_n$ have measure zero then so does $A$ which is absurd, hence there exists $B=A\cap E_j$ such that $\mu (B)>0$. Note that $B\subset A$ and $B \in F$ since $A\in F$ and $E_j \in F$.

Clearly $B\subset E_j$ and therefore $\mu (B)≤\mu(E_j)<\infty$

Comment: you did not use the fact that $\mu$(A)=$\infty$. How does it relate to the problem?

Comment: @user212436 I did use it: "If all the sets $A\cap E_n$ have measure zero so does $A$ which is absurd". The contradiction follows from the fact that $\mu (A)=\infty$ and hence $\mu (A) \neq 0$.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks for spending time to answer it. I do appreciate it.